# how can I catch the exception when I use promise.all[] or stop the chain call

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm a little confused about the usage of Promise. 
Please see the examples below:

**Q1. How can I stop the chain call?**

```js
const wait = (duration = 0) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, duration);
  });
};

const asyncTask1 = () => {
  return wait(1000).then(() => {
    console.log('task1 takes 1s.');
  });
};

const asyncTask2 = () => {
  return wait(3000).then(() => {
    console.log('task2 takes 3s.');
  });
};

Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => {
    asyncTask1();
  })
  .then(() => {
    asyncTask2();
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log('fail.');
  });
```

As the code shows, `asyncTask2` won't run until `asyncTask1` has completed. But the question is how can I stop the chain call if `asyncTask1` fails. Namely `asyncTask2` won't run because the `asyncTask1` fails
.
Note: no error or exception generated in asyncTask1, I want to use a status (success or failed) to decide the result of asyncTask1.

**Q2. How can I know which task generates the exception when I use Promise.all()?**

```js
const wait = (duration=0) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, duration);
  });
};

const asyncTask1 = () => {
  return wait(1000).then(() => {
    console.log('task1 takes 1s.');
  });
};

const asyncTask2 = () => {
  return wait(3000).then(() => {
    console.log('task2 takes 3s.');
  });
};

Promise
  .all([asyncTask2(), asyncTask1()])
  .then(() => {
    console.log('all done.');
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log('error');
  });
```

The code above can run successfully, but if `asyncTask1` or `asyncTask2` fails, it will go into the catch function. So the question is how can I know whether the exception is from `asyncTask1` or `asyncTask2`?

Comment: Just throw a unique error for each and then you can examine the error to see which error it is.  Other than that, there is no way to know when using `Promise.all()`.  It only reports the first rejection with no report of which one it was.

Comment: it may interest you to know that `new Promise` executor function takes **two** arguments ... `new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject('blah'))` will reject the promise rather than resolve/fulfil it

Comment: "*As the code shows, asyncTask2 won't run until asyncTask1 has completed.*" - Nope. For that, you would need to have the task promise `return`ed from the `then` callback, otherwise it won't be awaited in the chain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.map()` to call the functions set at an array, `throw` the `index` of the element where error occurs within `.map()` callback at `.catch()`

```js
const wait = (duration=0) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, duration);
  });
};

const asyncTask1 = () => {
  return wait(1000).then(() => {
    console.log('task1 takes 1s.');
  });
};

const asyncTask2 = () => {
  return wait(3000).then(() => {
    throw new Error()
    console.log('task2 takes 3s.');
  });
};

let arr = [asyncTask2, asyncTask1];

Promise
  .all(arr.map((p, index) => 
     p().catch(err => {throw new Error(err + " at index " + index)})))
  .then(() => {
    console.log('all done.');
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log('error', e);
  });
```